# Is this matrix diagonalizable for every value of $k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

If I have a matrix

$$\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -2 & 0\\
0 & 2 & k \\
0 & 0 & 3
\end{pmatrix}$$

finding the eigen values and eigenvectors:

with eigenvalues 2 and 3 and eigenvectors $\ v =(-2k,k,1)$ and $\ v1 = (1,0,0)$, is the matrix diagonalizable?

Comment: I was given a matrix I found the eigen values and eigen vectors

Comment: Please edit your post to show us your matrix and how you found these values and vectors. + I don't understand what "every number is a multiple of 1" has to do with your problem.

Comment: Yet a general fact: if the number of independent eigenvectors is strictly lower that the dimension, the matrix is not diagonalizable (of course! this is the definition of diagonalizability...)

Comment: @AnneBauval see edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $J = \begin{pmatrix} 2&0&0 \\ 0&3&1 \\ 0&0&3 \end{pmatrix}$ and let $V = (v_1,v_2,v_3),$ where $v_3$ is chosen such that $V$ has linearly independent columns. Then the matrix $A = VJV^{-1}$ has *exactly* two eigenpairs, $(2, v_1)$, and $(3,v_2)$, but is not diagonalizable as it does not have a third eigenvector so that the eigenbasis spans the entire space.

Edit: This answer was given for a previous version of the question about whether the existence of two eigenpairs implies diagonalizability in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3):

For any $k$, your eigenvalues $2$ and $3$ and associated eigenspaces (generated respectively by $(1,0,0)$ and $(-2k,k,1)$) are correct, and sufficient to conclude that the matrix is *not* diagonalizable, since the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces, $1+1=2$, is strictly smaller than the dimension of the matrix, $3$.